# Bash script - Script that keeps track on script runtime

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, case

I want to create a bash script that can be started with start, stop and status and does this:

The start argument saves current time in a file (seconds from 1970 1/1).

The status argument shows the amount of time it has gone since the script started.

The stop argument stops the script and shows the amount of time it has been since the script started.

This is what I have, but something is wrong with the syntax at `fi` and `;;` but I dont understand why, i have followed the "case tutorial".

```
#!/bin/bash

#script to run timetrack

date=$(date +%s) #make an own variabel for seconds since 1970 1/1

case $1 in
    start)
      echo "Script started"
      echo $date > oldTime.txt #add the current time to oldTime.txt
      ;;

    status)
      echo "Script has been running:"
      if [ -e ./oldTime.txt ] then #check to see if the file exists
      difference=$(( $(date) - oldTime.txt)) #calculate the time the script 
      has been running

      printf "%s\n" "${difference#-}" #print out the time
      fi #dont know? stop script maybe?
      ;;

    stop)
      echo "Script will not stop and has been running:"
      if [ -e ./oldTime.txt ] then
      difference=$((date) - oldTime.txt))
      printf "%s\n" "${difference#-}"
      rm oldTime.txt #remove the file so when i start the script again it 
      starts from 0
      fi
      exit 1 #stops script?


      ;;
```

Comment: The correct bash syntax needs to put semicolon between the *test* and *then* -> `if[ condition ]; then` . Or just put *then* on a new line -> http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples

Comment: Copy paste your script in http://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the errors as it reports

Comment: +1 on shellcheck.net. Also, in your `stop)` case, you'll need to use `date '+%s'` when calculating `$difference`.